# Is there such a thing as a ViewModel equivalent in Yii? If so, how to implement one

Tags: view, model, yii, viewmodel

I am just learning Yii, and I am able to create ActiveRecord models which map to the database tables.

Is there such a thing as a viewmodel implementation in Yii as I can't find any kind of documentation. Maybe it's called something else?

Example:

I have a `product` table and a `category` table of which I wish to expose the following columns in the viewmodel.

```
product.id
category.name
product.name
product.price
```

I am aware that I can do this by referring to the fields as such individually within Yii, however the above is a cleaner / simpler version of my real much more complex database.

As such, a ViewModel functionality whereby I can expose the columns which I want to, and then re-use it wherever I need to without repeating code would be quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

Yii1 doesn't have a view model per se, although it's coming in Yii2. Instead, pass your values as parameters to your render method in your controller and refer to them by name in your view ...